# Setting a permission for any future file created in this directory

Tags: linux, permissions

Hi can I make in linux any future file created in some directory, writable.

Thank you

gidi

Comment: Did you consider using ACLs?

Comment: I'm not the admin so, it sounds too big step for this aim

Answer (score 2):

Use `umask`. For instance :

```
umask 0000
```

Will make files created afterwards (ie, in the same session) have the rw permissions for everyone :

```
-rw-rw-rw-
```

Should you want to make that change persistant, just place it into `~/.bashrc` (assuming your shell is bash).

`umask` works by bit-masking the default permissions used on file creation, check its man page for more details.

Comment: Thanks. How can I set this for a single specific directory?

Comment: Short answer : you can't, `umask` works on a per-session basis. I had overlooked this requirement in your question. If you can't use ACLs, I guess you could hack something into your user's `.bashrc` to set the umask only when in this specific directory.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the setuid-bit on a directory to force all created files to a specific group.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories

Comment: This is nice, but will not do the trick